# Directories are missing in recovery mode

Tags: debian, filesystems, data-recovery

My service provider booted my virtual server in the recovery mode and now I'm a little bit lost.

I'd like to save some files from my web-directory but I can't find `/var/www`. Though there are files in `/var/` but not my `/www/` folder. Is this a normal thing in recovery mode and what do I have to do to save my files?

Comment: It could be `/var/www` is on a different filesystem; is there an entry for it in `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Nope. These is the fstab content

none / aufs defaults 0 0
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
#/dev/nfs        /               nfs     defaults 0 0
none            /tmp            tmpfs   defaults 0 0
none            /var/run        tmpfs   defaults 0 0
none            /var/lock       tmpfs   defaults 0 0
none            /var/tmp        tmpfs   defaults 0 0
none            /var/log        tmpfs   defaults 0 0

Comment: Is `/var/www` a symlink? Does `readlink -f /var/www` give anything other than `/var/www`?

Comment: Nope, it only returns `/var/www`

Answer (score 0):

I believe a lot of service providers will provide a recovery mode similar to this one: http://wiki.vps.net/recovery-mode/.

*excerpt*

> #### Recovery Mode
>
> The recovery console is activated by clicking on the **“Reboot in
>   Recovery”** option. This will cause for your VPS to be rebooted into
>   the recovery image.
>
> The login details are
>
> ```
>   IP: Your normal IP 
>   Username: root 
>   Password: recovery
> ```
>
> Once connected you will be put into a recovery shell.
>
> Your filesystem will be on `/dev/xvdb1`
>
> To `fsck` (check) the filesystem run `fsck -y /dev/xvdb1`
>
> To mount the filesystem run `mount /dev/xvdb1 /mnt`. Once the filesystem
>   is mounted you can then edit files/copy information of as required.
>
> Once you have completed the recovery just click **“Reboot”** in the
>   control panel and the system will boot back to your normal OS.

So I'd take a look at what HDD's are available to you once you've booted into recovery mode.

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="ce55950a-2dfe-4dc4-84b9-079d4b36f3e3" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="jmEnPF-vjb6-PrHJ-BQ4s-0jpw-YjO5-47Q7be" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="Y82rfl-jW79-6MQn-3W5A-Kaw4-i1ma-i986HJ" TYPE="LVM2_member"
```

Your original partition is likely listed here, you can `fsck` it, like above, and then manually mount it.

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Be sure to `umount` it when you're ready to reboot your system.

Comment: mhm, I get this output, when I try to mount sda1 and xvdb1: mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: @Leagis - can you show the output of `blkid`?

Comment: Sure
`/dev/vda1: UUID="aca6b9f3-4d6e-4c9b-a3e6-7b414942d497" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/vda5: UUID="98ac7625-4d6e-43ff-b67d-dc07a5d5fa36" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/vda6: UUID="af809eeb-df5c-43c1-be81-d89e87fdff11" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/vda7: UUID="5d2eecc9-3720-4870-acab-c783815e2228" TYPE="swap"
/dev/vda8: UUID="76f3fe44-4e88-4ebe-a97f-adf2b3cdd148" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/vda9: UUID="9eaaf280-f68f-4314-81ed-be20b3d8ac8c" TYPE="ext4" `

Comment: @Leagis - who's the service provider?

Comment: You should be mounting like this: `mount /dev/vda1 /mnt` to see if it works. These are all ext4 so you shouldn't need to specify the filesystem type to `mount`.

Comment: Service Provider is a german company called netcup. `mount /dev/vda1 /mnt` works without a problem.

Comment: @Leagis - I'd go through those `/dev/vda*` devices and find the one that has `/var/www` on it.

Comment: How do I do this? Do I have to execute for e.g. `mount /dev/vda5 /mnt/` and then use `find /var/www` every time?

Comment: @Leagis - hard to say without seeing what's on each device when you mount it but yeah that's the approach I'd take. I wouldn't expect that when you mount it that it'll contain `/var/www` either just like that. You'll likely want to search for `www` or `find /mnt -type d -name "www"`

Comment: Mmh, I mounted all devices and executed `find /mnt -type d -name "www"` but I don't get any results.

Comment: @Leagis - is your data typically mounted underneath `/var/www`? If these `/dev/vda*` devices are then that would explain why there is no `/var/www`. I'd need to see the top levels of the `/dev/vda*` devices after mounting to confirm this though.

Comment: No, the `/var/www` is only my directory which contains my websites. Okay, what do I need to do?

Comment: @Leagis - the top level of each of those `/dev/vda*`'s.